# jQuery working in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox or IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am rather stumped by some JavaScript/jQuery code I've written working perfectly in Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), but not working at all in Firefox or IE and I am hoping someone could point out my error?

What I'm doing is pulling in a GeoRSS feed with jQuery and then plotting the location points on a map using Leaflet. Somehow the points are not being plotted when using Firefox or IE?
Here's the page in question: http://bit.ly/19N0I75

And here's the code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'primitive.geography-class').setView([42, 22], 4);

var wordpressIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'http://www.shifting-sands.com/wp-content/themes/shiftingsands/images/icons/wordpress.png',

iconSize:     [18, 18], // size of the icon
shadowSize:   [0, 0], // size of the shadow
iconAnchor:   [9, 9], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
shadowAnchor: [0, 0],  // the same for the shadow
popupAnchor:  [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$.get("http://shifting-sands.com/feed/", function (data) {
var $xml = $(data);
var $i = 0;
$xml.find("item").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        item = {
            title: $this.find("title").text(),
            linkurl: $this.find("link").text(),
            description: $this.find("description").text(),
            pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
            latitude: $this.find("lat").text(),
            longitude: $this.find("long").text()
        }

                lat = item.latitude;
                long = item.longitude;
                title = item.title;
                clickurl = item.linkurl;

                //Get the url for the image.
                var htmlString = '<h4><a href="' + clickurl + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></h4>';                       
                var contentString = '<div id="content">' + htmlString + '</div>';   

                //Create a new marker position using the Leaflet API.
                var rssmarker = L.marker([lat, long], {icon: wordpressIcon}).addTo(map);

                //Create a new info window using the Google Maps API

                rssmarker.bindPopup(contentString, {closeButton: true});


    $i++;
});
});
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works on firefox 24 - mac

Comment: "invalid LatLng object" ?

Comment: "Error: Invalid LatLng object: (, )" in mapbox.js. As a guess I'd say there's a trailing comma after the last property in an object literal.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I was thinking something similar, but why would it say _Invalid LatLng object_ rather than report a more generic syntax error? Javascript doesn't know anything about LatLng objects. I suspect this error is being reported by mapbox.js, complaining about some input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the lat value is namespaced (geo:lat), you get no value out of your `find()`. Hence the error `(,)`, two empty values, separated by a comma. You have to alter your query to this:

```
latitude: $this.find("geo\\:lat").text()
```

The double backslash escapes the colon.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Confusingly, however, this breaks it in Chrome, Safari, and Opera.
Here's the map with your changes: http://bit.ly/19XLQEL

Comment: Solved it! A bug in jQuery means that it needs to be
`latitude: $this.find("geo\\:lat, lat").text()`
`longitude: $this.find("geo\\:long, long").text()`